# open random php pages from array list when I click next

Tags: php, arrays, random, shuffle

I've hit a dead end. I've been working on this for 3 weeks with no result.

I have 10 php pages (`1.php`, `2.php`, ..., `10.php`) and a starting page (`start.php`).

All I want to do is randomize the 10 pages with no repeat, so when I click "next" in the `start.php` it should go to one of the 10 pages (let's say for example it goes to `4.php`). When I click "next" in `4.php` it should redirect to another within the 10 pages except for `4.php`.

It should continue this until all the numbers (`1.php` - `10.php`) have been displayed. At this point it should randomize again. When I click "next" in the last number `.php` displayed, it should randomize the number and go back to the first on the random list.

Here's what I have so far:

`start.php`:

```
<?php $vidcount = 1; ?>
<? include ("source.php"); ?>
<a href="$nextvid[$vidcount].php">next page</a>
```

`source.php`:

```
<?php 
include ("start.php");

$numbers = range(1, $total_songs);

if(($vidcount == $total_songs)||($vidcount == 1)){
shuffle($numbers);
$vidcount = 1;
}

$nextvid[1] = $numbers[0];
$nextvid[2] = $numbers[1];
$nextvid[3] = $numbers[2];
$nextvid[4] = $numbers[3];
$nextvid[5] = $numbers[4];
$nextvid[6] = $numbers[5];
$nextvid[7] = $numbers[6];
$nextvid[8] = $numbers[7];
$nextvid[9] = $numbers[8];
$nextvid[10] = $numbers[9];
?>
```

`1.php`, `2.php`, ... `10.php`:

```
<?php
include("source.php");?>
<?php echo $vidcount; ?>

<a href="testrun[<?php echo $nextvid[$vidcount];  ?>].php">next page</a>
<?php $vidcount++;?>
```

`1.php` - `10.php` have the same code. I also have a `source.php` which is supposed to keep track of what number has been displayed and re-shuffle when all the numbers have been displayed.

Please help. I'll greatly appreciate any help I can get.

You don't have to use the above code, I don't mind starting from scratch if you have a different idea as long as the code I get works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well firstly why do you have ten files when you could just have one file and `?id=X` in the URL? But never mind that.

Your best bet is to use a session variable. Something like this:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if( !isset($_SESSION['sequence']) || !$_SESSION['sequence']) {
        $_SESSION['sequence'] = shuffle(range(1,10));
    }
    $next = array_shift($_SESSION['sequence']);
    // now use $next to create your "Next page" link.
?>
```

Comment: thanks Kolink for your response. I have 10 files because that was the only way I could get a new page to load. FYI I'm not very good at PHP I just started learning because of the project I'm working on.

Comment: Kolink, I'm not quite sure how to incorporate the code you've provided into mine. Will you be willing to work with me on this? I will send you a little thank you gift through paypal :) Here's my email solow01(at)gmail.com